# Operaciones booleanas entre columnas en pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Quiero recorrer una columna de mi dataframe llamada 'Resultados partidos' para que si esta tiene un valor positivo me devuelva un True.

Yo hago esto:

```
valor = True
if df(['Resultados partidos']) > 0:
    valor = True
```

Posteriormente ya haré otras operaciones. El problema es que me dice que este if así no se puede hacer, e imagino que es porque no está bien este `df(['Resultados partidos']). ¿Cómo se hace para acceder a él?

En concreto el error es:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

¡`Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al poner paréntesis en tu expresión:

```
if df(['Resultados partidos']) > 0:
```

estás diciendo a python que *invoque* el objeto `df`, como si fuera una función, ya que los paréntesis detrás de un identificador son la forma de invocar una función. El error que te da es que el objeto `df` no es *callable* (no es una función), cosa que ya sabíamos.

Más cercano a lo que buscas sería:

```
df['Resultados partidos'] > 0
```

En este caso el lado izquierdo antes del `>` es una columna completa del dataframe. No es un solo número. Sin embargo lo estamos comparando con 0, que si es un solo número ¿funcionará esa comparación? ¿qué hará?

Sí que funcionará porque Pandas ha redefinido el operador `>` para el caso en que el lado izquierdo sea un dataframe o una columna (una *Series*), y hacer una operación vectorial para ese caso. Es decir, lo que hará pandas será comparar cada uno de los elementos de la columna con cero. El resultado de esa comparación será otra columna, pero esta vez de valores `True` o `False`, según cada elemento de la columna original sea mayor de cero o no.

Si intentas usar esa expresión como parte de un `if` así:

```
if df['Resultados partidos'] > 0:
```

tendrás un error, ya que al `if` no le estás pasando una expresión que sea `True`  o `False`, sino como ya hemos dicho una columna con muchos `True` y `False`. No está claro si una columna así debe ser equivalente a `True`, o a `False`, por lo que obtendrías el error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
            a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Que más o menos está diciendo lo que acabo de explicar, que una `Series` (que es lo que ve el `if`) no puede traducirse de forma obvia a un "valor de verdad" (es decir, a `True` o a `False`).

En tu caso quieres detectar que haya un valor positivo en la columna, es decir que *al menos uno de los resultados sea `True`*. La función `any()` sirve justo para eso. Recibe una serie de valores `True` o `False`, y retorna `True` si hay al menos un `True`.

Por tanto harías:

```
if any(df['Resultados partidos'] > 0):
    valor = True
else:
    valor = False
```

O aún más directo:

```
valor = any(df['Resultados partidos'] > 0)
```

### Actualización (expresiones booleanas más complejas)

Si se quiere una condición más compleja, como que muestre `True` o `False` según condiciones en diferentes columnas, puede hacerse mediante una expresión como la siguiente:

```
(df['Resultados partidos'] > 0) & (df['Otra columna'] > 1)
```

Como ves, esto no es precisamente igual que cuando se hacen comparaciones en python de variables "normales" (por ejemplo enteros), donde la sintaxis sería:

```
 a > 0 and b > 1
```

Python no necesita paréntesis alrededor de las comparaciones individuales, y usa `and` en lugar de `&`. La precedencia del `>` es más alta que la de `and`, por lo que evalúa por separado las expresiones `a>0` y `b>1` y después hace el `and` entre cada una de ellas.

Sin embargo cuando usamos pandas la sintaxis es otra. ¿Cómo es posible? Pandas no puede alterar el parser de python, por lo que tiene que ingeniárselas para redefinir operadores que *ya existieran en python* y darles otros significados.

Hemos visto que por ejemplo redefine `>` para que, si lo que hay a la izda es un dataframe o una series, haga una comparación *vectorial* de todas las filas. Si pudiera redefinir de la misma forma el significado de `and` (*spoiler*: no se puede) la siguiente expresión podría funcionar bajo pandas:

```
df['col1']>0 and df['col2']>1
```

Python evaluaría primero `df['col1']>0` que gracias a la magia Pandas produciría un vector de booleanos, después `df['col2']>1`, que produciría un segundo vector de booleanos, y finalmente haría un `and` entre ambos vectores. Python no sabe cómo hacer un `and` entre vectores, por lo que fallaría en este punto. Pero si pudiéramos redefinir `and` para que Pandas se haga cargo de esa operación, haciéndola vectorialmente (es decir, fila a fila), el problema estaría resuelto.

Por desgracia **no se puede redefinir el significado de `and`**, y tampoco el de `or` ni `not`.

La solución adoptada por pandas es muy ingeniosa, pero por desgracia rompe con la sintaxis esperada por los usuarios y causa no pocos problemas. Lo que han hecho ha sido **redefinir el operador `&`**, que existía ya en python (si bien no con el significado booleano, sino para hacer operaciones a nivel de bits), para que funcione con dataframes. De la misma forma han redefinido también `|` (que era el operador para la operación OR a nivel de bits) para que haga el equivalente a `or` y `~` (que era el operador para la operación de negación de bits, o complemento a 1) para que haga la negación lógica `not` vectorial.

El problema es que:

- El usuario debe usar una sintaxis que aunque no es del todo anti-intuitiva, no es la típica de python. No puede usar `and`, `or` ni `not` como parte de la expresión booleana, sino `&`,  `|` y `~` en su lugar.
- **Peor aún**, la precedencia de esos operadores no coincide con la de los booleanos que pretende emular. Tienen una precedencia más alta incluso que los comparadores `>` y similares.

Debido al segundo punto, es necesario poner paréntesis alrededor de las comparaciones, para forzar a que se evalúen antes. Así la expresión siguiente funcionará:

```
(df['Resultados partidos'] > 0) & (df['Otra columna'] > 1)
```

porque Python, al ver los paréntesis, evaluará primero cada comparador (operación que pandas hará vectorialmente gracias a la redefinición de `>`) y después hará la operación `&` entre ambos vectores (cosa que de nuevo hará pandas gracias a la redefinición del operador `&`).

Si no ponemos paréntesis, ya que `&` tiene mayor precedencia que `>`, lo que  python hará sería equivalente a:

```
df['Resultados partidos'] >  (0 & df['Otra columna']) > 1
```

Y producirá el error:

```
The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**Explicación extra**

El por qué la última expresión produce un error tiene una explicación interesante, y en cierto modo es una afortunada casualidad, ya que en vez de un error podría haber producido un resultado erróneo, más difícil de detectar.

Lo que ocurre es que, si miras la última expresión verás que en el fondo tiene esta estructura:

```
algo > otro > 1
```

Este tipo de desigualdades "encadenadas" son útiles. Por ejemplo, para saber si un número es positivo y menor de 10, se puede poner `0 < numero < 10`. Porque son útiles el lenguaje las soporta, pero para resoverlas las convierte en:

```
algo > otro and otro > 1
```

Así pues nuestra expresión pandas que nos causa problemas en realidad equivale a:

```
df['Resultados partidos'] >  (0 & df['Otra columna']) and (0 & df['Otra columna']) > 1
```

En este caso Python comienza por resolver `0 & df['Otra columna']`, operación que Pandas convierte en un "and lógico vectorial" y daría un vector lleno de `False`, pues está haciendo un `0 and valor` para cada valor del vector, y `0` equivale a `False`. Después evalúa el `>` de la izquierda, cosa que hará también vectorialmente para obtener otro vector lleno de `False`, y finalmente hará el `>` de la derecha (que le dará también `False` porque está comparando `False>1` para cada elemento del vector).

Finalmente por tanto llega al `and`, que tiene que comparar un vector lleno de `False` con otro vector lleno de `False`. Este es el `and` "normal" de python, sin redefinir, el cual no sabe comparar vectores y es quien emite el mensaje final de error.

Comment: Gracias pero no quiero que *al menos uno de los resultados sea True* quiero la solución anterior. Que vaya línea a línea y para cada una escribir un True o False. Es decir,  `df['Resultados partidos'] > 0`

Comment: Rizando el rizo, si quisiera que la respuesta de true o false fuera por dos condiciones, ¿cómo lo haría? he probado `df['Resultados partidos'] > 0 & df['Otra columna'] > 1` pero me da error. ¿Cuando es más de una ya no va bien así? Me da un error de tipo, diciendo que no se puede comparar float con bool.

Comment: @NEA Para expresiones booleanas más complejas pandas parece tener su propia sintaxis, en la que `&` se usa en vez de `and`, pero además **hay que poner paréntesis** en lugares donde python aparentemente no los necesitaría. Acabo de extender la respuesta para explicar los porqués y las trampas de esta sintaxis.

Comment: @NEA Me he permitido también cambiar el título de tu pregunta, para que se ajuste más al verdadero problema y ayude a quien lo necesite a encontrar la explicación que acabo de escribir.